# PHP Does not let me query a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database where I can make queries to all tables without problems except for the 'employees' table. I tried making this basic query in php:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
require "init.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados;";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $response[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

... and I do not get any results. However when I run this query for other tables, it works well, what can it be?

[image]

This same query works fine from phpmyadmin

NEWS: if you use `SELECT DNI FROM empleados` it works, if I use `SELECT * FROM empleados` it doesn't.... (DNI is the key, is it possible that I can only access the primary key?)

Comment: I'd start with not hiding all errors with `error_reporting(0);` ...

Comment: I delete the sentence and get the same result, nothing. Same with error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Try changing it to `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if errors are shown... maybe also try `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` right after `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: Same result, nothing

Comment: The strange thing is that if I do the same query for another table it works ...

Comment: Are you certain that data is getting *into* the table? Or is the table actually empty because of some other issue?

Comment: The table has data I'm watching right now and I've added more right now

Comment: you're not checking for errors via php and the query; do that.

Comment: So what is your solution

Comment: you replace `error_reporting(0);` with `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you add `if(!$result){ echo "Error " . mysqli_error($con); }` after `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);`

Comment: `require "init.php";` that is unknown as to what is in there. Also make sure you chose the right database and that file isn't stopping anything from going any further.

Comment: @Pablo you're going to have to ping me directly like I did here for you with the @ symbol followed by my name and a space after it; I stayed in the question too long waiting for an update. Good luck, I have to leave now.

Comment: thank you @Fred -ii- i solved my problem... the problem was that in Spanish we have special characters like à ò .... The only thing I had to do is remove these special characters from the entries and now  the query works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with special characters such as Spanish accents, if you remove these the query works correctly

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are not connecting to database.
Try this.

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

Do not forget to change the credentials.

Comment: this setence is on init.php (working well with other query)<?php

error_reporting(0);

$db_name = "app";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "";
$server_name = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name);

if(!$con){
 echo '{"message":"Unable to connect to the database."}';
}

?>